# How to continuously restart/loop R script

Tags: r

I want an R script to continuously run and check for files in a folder and do something with those files.

The code simply checks for a file, then moves the file to somewhere else and renames it, deleting the old file (in reality it's a bit more elabore than this).

If I run the script it works fine, however I want R to automatically detect for the files. In other words, is there a way to have R run the script continuously so that I don't have to run the script if I put files in that folder?

Comment: Why don't you use a cron job to launch the R script?

Comment: Or, probably less efficient, but easier(?) on Windows, have the code in a function which is then called within a forloop?

Comment: depending on your OS there may be better solution than doing it in R

Comment: Under Linux (but not under R) you could look at `inotify`, which allows to monitor file and directories change in real time.

Comment: On windows `Autohotkey` is quite good for scripting things like this. Ofcourse only if it is just about moving files around.. for any file content manipulation which R can do better, go with R..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In pure R you just need an infinite `repeat` loop...

```
repeat {
  print('Checking files')
  # Your code to do file manipulation

  Sys.sleep(time=5)  # to stop execution for 5 sec

}
```

However there may be better tools suitable to do this kind of file manipulation depending on your OS.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra Or just use Rscript

Comment: Great, this works exactly like I want it to. I will be running various of these scripts in line to convert and manipulate files in various stages. This simple scripting will also be able to help me with doing that. I will be doing it on windows and don't have any knowledge of other relevant programming languages so this works very well. Thanks!

Comment: Well now to think of it, for windows, doing everything in R might itself be better solution. To stop the loop all you have to do is press Escape.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `tclTaskSchedule` from the tcltk2 package to schedule a function or expression to run on a regular interval.  You can have multiple such tasks scheduled and still work in the R session (just be careful not to modify something that the scheduled task could also modify or you can get unpredictable results).

Though an OS based solution that runs a given rscript may still be a better approach.